# ApplicationRollBackException not shown in primefaces messages

Tags: primefaces, ejb, stateless

Currently one of my stateless class is throwing an exception annotated with applicationException with rollback=true. This exception is caught in the bean class and added successfully to the faces messages, but for some reason it is not shown.

My setup:
bean->service (throw exception here) - ok
bean->service->service (throw here) - failed

bean is annotated with:
@Named
@ViewScoped (omnifaces)

while service is Stateless.

Seems like session is lost on the second service. Any idea why?

Here is my exception class:

```
@ApplicationException(rollback = true)
public class BusinessException extends Exception
```

Comment: You state _"This exception is caught in the bean class and added successfully to the faces messages,"_. You can only add text to the faces message not a full exception, so this in no way related to the exception. Maybe you do a 'redirect' on errors like this and the message does not survive. Please create an [mcve]. The amount of info you post now only results in guessing.

Comment: Does it work if you use an `h:messages` instead of the PrimeFaces one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution seem rather weird note that: BusinessException extends Exception, so in my code I have:

```
try {
   //..
} catch (Exception e) {
  messages.error(e.getMessage());
}
```

But that doesn't work, but this does:

```
try {
   //..
} catch (BusinessException e1) {     
  messages.error(e1.getMessage());
} catch (Exception e) {
  messages.error(e.getMessage());
}
```

The idea is to catch the BusinessException itself and not its parent. But I don't know why that is.